# Can I invert this expression with an integral transform?

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-transforms

Let $$ T(t) = 1 - \int_{\tau = 0}^\infty a(\tau) \mathrm{e}^{-t/\tau} d\tau. $$where $t \in (0, \infty)$. I know $ T(t) $ and would like to find $ a(\tau) $. This looks like a Laplace transform but the limits of integration are the wrong way round. Can I find $ a(\tau) $ using an integral transform?

Comment: you can make a integral transform by $\frac{1}{\tau}$ and then apply the reverse Laplace transform of $T(t)-1$. This gives you $a(\frac{1}{\tau})\frac{1}{\tau^2}$.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see where the $\frac{1}{\tau^2}$ comes from. Could you explain that a little?

Comment: $d(1/\tau)= -\frac{1}{\tau^2} d\tau$ thus $1-T(t)$ is the Laplace transform of $a(\frac{1}{\tau})\frac{1}{\tau^2}$. If your integral converges absolutely then $a(\frac{1}{\tau})\frac{1}{\tau^2}$ is $L^1$ and if its derivative is also $L^1$ then the inverse Laplace transform integral converges absolutely and uniformly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T(t)=1-\int_0^\infty a(\tau)e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}~d\tau$

$\int_\infty^0a\left(\dfrac{1}{\tau}\right)e^{-t\tau}~d\left(\dfrac{1}{\tau}\right)=1-T(t)$

$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{1}{\tau^2}a\left(\dfrac{1}{\tau}\right)e^{-t\tau}~d\tau=1-T(t)$

$\mathcal{L}_{\tau\to t}\left\{\dfrac{1}{\tau^2}a\left(\dfrac{1}{\tau}\right)\right\}=1-T(t)$

$\dfrac{1}{\tau^2}a\left(\dfrac{1}{\tau}\right)=\delta(\tau)-\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{t\to\tau}\left\{T(t)\right\}$

$a\left(\dfrac{1}{\tau}\right)=\tau^2\delta(\tau)-\tau^2\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{t\to\tau}\left\{T(t)\right\}$

$a(\tau)=\dfrac{1}{\tau^2}\delta\left(\dfrac{1}{\tau}\right)-\dfrac{1}{\tau^2}\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{t\to\frac{1}{\tau}}\left\{T(t)\right\}$